# What are the requirements for grass height around runways and taxiways?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, airport-lighting

I am looking for the requirements for grass heights around runway and taxiway edges, signs and lights?

Comment: Do you have a specific country in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The faa limits grass height around 12 inches in the United States. http://bettervm.basf.us/frequently-asked-questions/case-studies/small-airport-with-big-history-cuts-cost,-time-&-mowing-with-vegetation-management.html

Comment: I am specifically asking the grass height around the taxiway lighting, signs and Runway edges inside the United States.

Comment: This link is dead