# Where does the FAA state requirements for how long grass can be?

Tags: faa-regulations, ground-operations

Working on a maintenance program for my local southwest airport, can you tell me what FAA document specifically states that the FAA recommends grass or turf height to be 5 to 8 inches?

Comment: "Turff"? - Turf?

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45552/62), although that question doesn't say which country or regulator it's asking about and there's no useful answer (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this Advisory Circular. There are numerous recommendations involving vegetation, but I couldn't find specific heights for grass mentioned. It DOES recommend lower growing turf, and discing or plowing taller grasses (milo, ryegrass) before they can seed out.

https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/150_5200-33